# Why does this RewriteRule work for 301 redirect but nothing else?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/white/(.*)/$ /$1/$2/?tags=white [R=301,L]
```

It works and changes the following:

```
http://bag-saver.com/uk/shop/white/clutch-bags/
```

into:

```
http://bag-saver.com/uk/shop/clutch-bags/?tags=white
```

But, I don't want the 301. I want to simply rewrite the URL. I've tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/white/(.*)/$ /$1/$2/?tags=white [QSA,L]
```

But as soon as I remove the R=301, I get page not found errors.

Why is this?

Edit - here are the rest of the rules in place:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-[0-9]{9}[0-9]+/$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/white/(.*)/$ /$1/$2/?tags=white [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Does the `/uk/shop/clutch-bags/?tags=white` actually resolve to something? Do you have other rules (the order is really important)?

Comment: Yes - /uk/shop/clutch-bags/?tags=white shows white clutch bags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [[P] flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/white/(.*)/$ /$1/$2/?tags=white [P]
```

**update**
other option is just remove the `R=301` to avoid forced redirect

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/white/(.*)/$ /$1/$2/?tags=white [L]
```

Comment: Thanks - so obvious that it should be P for proxy. I see some Performance Warnings for using P on that link you provided - any advice?

Answer (score -1):

To fix **page not found** error, you could try to set `index.php` as default page in Apache, if that is missing, to do that open the apache configuration file `httpd.conf` :

```
vi httpd.conf
```

Find out line that read as follows:

```
DirectoryIndex
```

Now set it as per your requirements:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
```

Save and close the file. Restart the Apache web server:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Please note that if you do not have access to Apache configuration file. Add `DirectoryIndex` to your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: This is not relevant to the question. The 'page not found' error was occurring for a page that exists.